# How to register window.external.notify event handler in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, acs

I'm trying to use Azure Access Control Service in HTML/JavaScript application. The following code sample is going to display token after authentication against selected identity provider:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleData (data){
    
        document.getElementById('tokenDiv').innerHTML = "Token = " + data;
    }
    function chooseIdentityProvider ( url ){
    
        document.getElementById('loginFrame').src = url;            
    }
    // HOW TO register notify event handler?    
    window.external.notify = handleData;        
</script>
<select name="AvailableProviders" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) chooseIdentityProvider (this.value)">
    <option value="-1">Select Identity Provider</option>
    <option value="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2faccesscontrol.windows.net%2f&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net%3a443%2fv2%2fwsfederation&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&wctx=pr%3djavascriptnotify%26rm%3duri%253awk%253atest">Windows Live ID</option>  
    <option value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0%2fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0%2fidentifier_select&openid.realm=https%3a%2f%2fnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net%3a443%2fv2%2fopenid&openid.return_to=https%3a%2f%2fnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net%3a443%2fv2%2fopenid%3fcontext%3dpr%253djavascriptnotify%2526rm%253duri%25253awk%25253atest%26provider%3dGoogle&openid.ns.ax=http%3a%2f%2fopenid.net%2fsrv%2fax%2f1.0&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=email%2cfullname%2cfirstname%2clastname&openid.ax.type.email=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fcontact%2femail&openid.ax.type.fullname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson&openid.ax.type.firstname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson%2ffirst&openid.ax.type.lastname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson%2flast">Google</option>
    <option value="https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth?openid.ns=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0%2fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0%2fidentifier_select&openid.realm=https%3a%2f%2fnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net%3a443%2fv2%2fopenid&openid.return_to=https%3a%2f%2fnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net%3a443%2fv2%2fopenid%3fcontext%3dpr%253djavascriptnotify%2526rm%253duri%25253awk%25253atest%26provider%3dYahoo!&openid.ns.ax=http%3a%2f%2fopenid.net%2fsrv%2fax%2f1.0&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=email%2cfullname%2cfirstname%2clastname&openid.ax.type.email=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fcontact%2femail&openid.ax.type.fullname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson&openid.ax.type.firstname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson%2ffirst&openid.ax.type.lastname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson%2flast">Yahoo!</option>"
</select> 
<br />
<iframe id="loginFrame" height="200" width="60%" src="" />
<br />
<div id="tokenDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of the iFrame is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try{
    window.external.notify(...token...);
}
catch(err){
    alert("Error ACS50021: windows.external.Notify is not registered.");
}
</script>
```

I'm getting error:

> "Error ACS50021: windows.external.Notify is not registered."

How can I register the notify event handler in the JavaScript?

Comment: Is this is in a browser or a "browser control"?

Comment: This is browser, and could be used in browser control on mobile devices wrapped by phonegap

Comment: I don't think browsers support this. I think it's just the browser control in .NET that does.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enable the allowed url to receive the message, something like this:

```
            // code needed -> allowed parameter to check all URL
        var unloadFunc = "(function(){ function navigating(){ window.external.notify('%%' + location.href);} window.onbeforeunload=navigating;return location.href;})();";
        var host = wv.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { unloadFunc });
        wv.AllowedScriptNotifyUris = new[] { new Uri(host) };
```

**wv** is the webview element in xaml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an iFrame you will need to use the postMessage API.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197015(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

window.external.notify is an API that only works in the XAML WebView control, or the HTML x-ms-webview control.